# Material Ui buttons disturbed issue in windows and mac systems

Tags: css, reactjs, algorithm, material-ui, frontend

Whenever i am deploying my webapp, the myi buttons are disturbed and same name classes are applied to button and width and they are changed. So how to resolve this ?

custom button file:

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { IconButton, IconButtonProps } from "@mui/material";

import useStyles from "./style";

interface Props extends BackButtonProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  width?:string,
  height?:string
}
const BackIconButton = ({
  children,
  className,
  onClick,
  disabled,
  color,
  width,
  height
}: Props) => {
  const classes = useStyles({ height, width});
  return (
    <IconButton
      className={`${className} ${classes.root} ${width ? classes.customButton : ""}`}
      onClick={onClick}
      disabled={disabled}
      disableRipple
      color={color || "secondary"}
    >
      {children}
    </IconButton>
  );
};
export default BackIconButton;
```

---

useStyle file:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  customButton:{
    width:(props:{height:string,width:string})=>props.width,
    height:(props:{height:string,width:string})=>props.height
  }
});

export default useStyles;
```

**I need to know how i can stop the disturbance of my buttons.**